# Loggoff script for phonegap

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

I have a phonegap app built using html5, css3 and jquery. I am trying for a function where user clicks on a logou button and it takes to a login screen but with clear fields. I mean When I just use the change page command and redirect it to login page, I stills ee the user name and password. I am simply using change page command:

```
function logoutbutton()
```

{

```
$.mobile.changePage("login.html");
```

}

What I should do so that when it redirects to login page, it clears the password field?

Comment: also div looks like <div class="toplogoutbutton" id="toplogoutbutton" onclick="logoutbutton();">
         </div>

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question.. can you use pageshow or pagebeforeshow event handlers and set input (login/password) fields' value to "" ? Assuming you are using jquery mobile text and password type input fields in html?